# Pull down to search iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I just need an idea of how to implement "Pull down to search" functionality in iPhone/iPad.
I have a UITableView and when I'm at the beginning of the tableView and scroll down, I want to show a searchBar (which is hidden at start up). And after that scrolling to the bottom of the tableView I want to hide the searchBar. I've looked over the internet for some ideas and possible solutions, but that ended with no success. I need something like when you scroll down the tableView to be pushed a little bit down.

Comment: Have you looked at 3rd party pull-to-refresh libraries to see how they work?

Comment: No I didn't. Thought I could implement searchBar and tableView in scrollView, but I'm still not sure about that. I will wait for another responses and if no a real solution is served, I will look at 3rd party pull-to-refresh libraries.

Comment: You just don't need the functionality. Don't hide important features from users. Apple doing wrong in many of their products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this thread: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670202/pull-down-to-show-view/21670426#21670426)

This solution works for me for a ViewController.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController() <UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic) UIView *viewSearch;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *txtSearch;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // view
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    // tableview
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 300)];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    // search view
    self.viewSearch = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [self.viewSearch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.viewSearch];

    // search textfield
    self.txtSearch = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 30)];
    [self.txtSearch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.txtSearch setPlaceholder:@"Search..."];
    [self.viewSearch addSubview:self.txtSearch];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (decelerate) {
        [self.txtSearch resignFirstResponder];
    }

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0);
        [self.txtSearch becomeFirstResponder];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        [self.txtSearch setText:@""];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate function in your controller, and show the search bar when the user scrolls the table to a content offset with a negative y coordinate.

The table view has to have bounce enabled for this to work.

Comment: So I need to add them (searchBar and tableView) in scrollView? Ok i will try this and tell you the result. Thank you.

Comment: No, the UITableView also IS a scroll view - if you set the view controller that contains the table view as the table delegate it will also receive the scroll delegate calls.

Comment: Ok, I tried your solution, but I have an issue here. When I hide the searchBar at viewWillAppear the place is still reserved for the searchBar and it's blank. Then I put in a custom View and set the frame.y of that view to a negative value but it seems it's not working. How can i hide my view (without setHidden)??

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `UITableViewController` to implement your functionality, you can use a `UIRefreshControl` to implement the "Pull down to search" behavior that you want. The table view controller has a `refreshControl` property that you can assign it to.

Hope this helps!