# Pull down to show view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have `UITableView`. I want to add a `UITextField` above tableView, which could be accessible by pulling tableView down. And I want to hide my textField by pulling tableView up. How can I do this?
Here's what I tried:

```
[self.messagesTableView addSubview:self.messageField];

- (UITextField*)messageField
{
    if (!_messageField)
    {
        _messageField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.messagesTableView.frame.size.width, kMessageFieldHeight)];
        _messageField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        _messageField.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    return _messageField;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == self.messagesTableView)
    {
        CGRect newFrame = self.messagesTableView.frame;
        newFrame.origin.y = self.messagesTableView.contentOffset.y + kMessageFieldHeight;
        self.messagesTableView.frame = newFrame;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is working for you ? Is textField getting added ?

Comment: @SamkitJain, yes it is added. But I can't properly show and hide textField

Comment: What is the problem? It it getting loaded in some time?

Comment: Does text field has fixed position?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have done such kind of functionality in my application. What i did just follow the steps.

1) Add `one view to negative position of tableView`. Here in this view you can add your textField or button whatever you want as per your requirement.

```
UIView *viewForSearchBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -50, 320, 50)];
viewForSearchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self._tableView addSubview:viewForSearchBar];
self._tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0);
```

2) now when user starts dragging tableview (actual scrollview of table view) you can call scrollview's delegate methods according it to test it.

When you dragging/scrolling tableView down then you will get contentOffset.y will be less then 0, I have explain here in code.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

    if (decelerate) {
        [txtSearch resignFirstResponder];
    }

    id<UILayoutSupport> topLayoutGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0)
    {
        UIView* hiddenHeader = ...; // this points to the hidden header view above
        CGRect headerFrame = [hiddenHeader frame];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
        self._tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(headerFrame.size.height + [topLayoutGuide length], 0, 0, 0);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

        self._tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake([topLayoutGuide length], 0, 0, 0);

        [UIView commitAnimations];   
    }
}
```

This two steps are working fine for me, as i have implemented. Let me add images to verify it.

[image]

[image]

if you still have any queries you can ask me.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 2.0:**

I worked out Nirav's answer in swift Xcode 7.1. Have a look.

```
let footerView = UIView()
let scroll = UIScrollView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var searchBar:UISearchBar?
    searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44))
    searchBar!.delegate = self
    searchBar!.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    footerView.addSubview(searchBar!)

    footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -50, 320, 50)
    footerView.backgroundColor =  UIColor.clearColor()
    self.listWrapTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0);
    self.listWrapTableView.addSubview(footerView)
        }
```

Adding scroll method using UIScrollViewDelegate.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
            if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0){
                print("greater than table height")
                UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
                UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.2)
                self.listWrapTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)
                UIView.commitAnimations()
            }
            else
            {
                UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
                UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.2)
                self.listWrapTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
                UIView.commitAnimations()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `UISearchBar` instead of `UITextField`.
And add it as `tableView's headerView`

Eg:

```
UISearchBar *mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
myTableIvew.tableHeaderView = mySearchBar;
```