# Pull Scrollview to reveal View - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uiscrollview

I'm trying to build something similar to IMessage's and WhatsApp's header in react native, where users can pull down to reveal a search bar in the header.

[image: pullToRevealView]

I have been able to pull down to reveal a hidden input, but because the scrollview's y value becomes negative on pull, it will bounce back to `y = 0` and prevent the input from sticking to the top. I have tried using both `translateY` and `scaleY` to reveal the hidden input.

```
class List extends Component {

  scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)

  render() {
    const translateY = this.props.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [ -50, 0 ],
      outputRange: [ 50, 0 ],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    })

   return (
    <>
       <Animated.View style={[
        styles.container,
        { transform: [ { translateY } ] },
       ]}>
          <Input />
       </Animated.View>

       <Animated.ScrollView
         onScroll={Animated.event(
           [ { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scrollY } } } ],
           { useNativeDriver: true }
          )}
         scrollEventThrottle={16}
       >
        {...}
       </Animated.ScrollView>
     </>
   )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    width: windowWidth,
    height: 50,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -50,
    zIndex: -99,
  },
});
```

I found this Stack Overflow post that has been useful to reference but it is IOS specific [Pull down to show view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670202/pull-down-to-show-view])

Comment: Not sure about React Native, but in iOS there's contentInset and contentOffset. You can create a tableHeaderView, then set the content offset to push the content above and under the fold. If you create a tableHeaderView, it automatically sets the inset; if you do it manually, you'll have to calculate the inset size and offset. Then you toss a view on top that is big enough to hide the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by using `contentOffset` and without any animations. I needed to make sure the scrollview was at least the size of the phone's `windowHeight` and then used `contentOffset` to push the initial y value of the `Scrollview` to the size of the header

```
      <ScrollView
        ListHeaderComponent={() => (
          <Header headerHeight={hiddenHeaderHeight} />
        )}
        contentContainerStyle={{ minHeight: windowHeight }}
        contentOffset={{ y: hiddenHeaderHeight }}
        ...
```

This solution works for a `Flatlist` as well.

One thing to note is `contentOffset` is an `ios` specific prop

Comment: how do u deal with the content above the header ( search input ), ie: Messages.

Comment: actually `contentOffset ` support has landed on android as well, either on 63.4 or 64 I'm not sure.

Comment: can you show the code? the headerHeight={hiddenheaderHeight} /> what for?