# OnScroll Fold the View - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm really bad at math, I am trying to calculate the top section of the scrollView as I want it to come on top of the top View to make more place for the scrollView.

I know that I could use `Animate.View` to accomplish this, But due to a component(`RecyclerListView`) Im unable to do that. So my Idee is while I scroll Down I move the component `ItemList` up until is at `-150` and when I scroll up, I will move until the value scrollY hit 0.

There is already a post here on Stack([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716264/pull-scrollview-to-reveal-view-react-native)) That displays what I want.

Here is my code.

```
<View> this is the View i want to cover/fold <View>
<ItemList style={{top:scrollY}}
    onScroll={(nativeEvent, offsetX, offsetY)=>{
       // when scroll down, scrollY should not exeede 0
       // when i scroll up, scrollY should not be more -150
        var maxScroll = 0; 
        var minScroll = -150; 
        // How should i calculate and set setScrollY()
    }}
    columnPerRaw={columnPerRar}
    itemHeight={150}
    onIni={(s: any) => {
      setScroll(s);
    }}
    onItemPress={(item, index) => itemClick(item as item)}
    items={data ?? []}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    onEndReached={() => {
      if (globalContext.value.panination && !isLoading)
        setEffectTrigger(Math.random());
    }}
    keyName="name"
  />
```

> Update

I have done like @Nnay said but its not to smoth

```
  var maxScroll = 0; // when i scroll up, scrollY should not be more then 0
                var minScroll = -150; // when scroll down, scrollY should not exeede -150
                var top = lastPos - offsetY;
                if (top >minScroll && top <=maxScroll)
                   setScrollY(top);
                lastPos = offsetY;
```

I have done it like

Answer (score 1):

no matter how you choose to trigger this behaviour (be it scroll position or scroll direction), you should probably use conditional classes.

to get the scroll direction, you will need to store the previous scroll position.
if `oldPosition - newPosition < 0` you have scrolled down, else you have scrolled up.

if you want the position of the element to trigger it, you should opt for setting a boolean to `true` or `false` which triggers the class. something like:

```
<View class={{this.show ? 'show' : ''}}>
```

where `show` is a boolean local to your component.

your `show` class can then handle the `height` of the element which will automatically push the following content down (provided it isn't positioned absolute) and you can smoothen this by using `transition: .25s` in css. otherwise it will jump

your scroll handler could then set the boolean depending on the scroll direction with something like:

```
this.show = oldPos - newPos > 0;
```

which will return `true` if the user has scrolled up which seems to be the behaviour you referenced in the link

let me know if this satisfies your question so I can edit and adapt the answer accordingly

ps: if you just set the `top` of your element while it has a static position, it won't work. also it will just jump to that position since you're not smoothing anything

EDIT: if CSS animations and transitions don't work and you cannot use react-native's `Animate.View`, the only option that doesn't require external packages is to set an interval animation if react-native doesn't support the [AnimationsAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API)

I haven't tried using the AnimationsAPI in react-native yet so I would advise to test that first since it's much more performant.

if you want to use the interval animation, I would still recommend sticking to the `boolean` solution above, but removing the class and adding a `height` variable in the `style` attribute of the `<View>`

make sure to store your interval in a variable so you can clear it.

```
if (this.height < 150 /* no idea what height you need, play around */ && show && !this.interval){ 
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.height += 1;
  }, 10)
} else if (this.height > 0 && !show && !this.interval) {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
   this.height -= 1;
  }, 10)
} else {
  clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```

something like this should work. keep in mind that I haven't used interval animations in years so you might need to play around with some values

Comment: Its way to easy to do it like you said, but what I want is to be able to slowly fold or move the component on top the view.

Comment: what's happening in the link you provided is the height of the search bar being animated between 0 and whatever height it needs depending on the scroll direction though.

the `transition` css property handles smoothing so if `.25s` is too fast, you can just increase the value.

do you want the `top` or `height` being set to a dynamic value depending on the scroll position rather than toggling between the states of `active` and `inactive` because that will break user experience

Comment: There is no transition in react native except using `Animate.View`.

Comment: @Alen.Toma sorry, my bad. https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations seems to be doing exactly what you need. alternatively there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-css-transition

Comment: Yes I know but the guide is using a scrollView of which im unable to use. `RecyclerListView` has its own scrollview that im unable to touch. I only have onScroll event. could you write a little example on this? would be really helpful.

Comment: difficult to write an example that works with `RecyclerListView` since I haven't worked with that. sorry. alternatively you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-css-transition, or 'react-transition-group'. there's a very helpful guide for the latter here: https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-implement-smooth-transitions-in-react-bd0497b06b8

Comment: Was able to make it happen with `Animate.View` but its a little laggy. Well i have to like it any way there is no batter until i find a time